# how to combine contents of one string to the contents of another string

Tags: python

this is my code:

```
 tasks_file = open("tasks.txt", "r+")
    for line in tasks_file:
        info = "Assigned to | Task | Task description | Date assigned | Due date | Task complete"
        string1 = info.split("|")
        for i in string1:
            print(i)
        string2 = line.split(",")
        for x in string2:
            print(x)
            
        output = i + ":" + x
        print(output)
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is combine each separate item in string1 with each separate item in string2. But the code only combines the last separate items and not the whole thing. Please assist in any way that you can. Thanks

task file contents:
admin, Register Users with taskManager.py, Use taskManager.py to add the usernames and passwords for all team members that will be using this program., 10 Oct 2019, 20 Oct 2019, No
admin, Assign initial tasks, Use taskManager.py to assign each team member with appropriate tasks, 10 Oct 2019, 25 Oct 2019, No

desired output:(an example of how the output should be like)

```
Task:          Assign initial task
Assigned to:   Admin
Date assigned: 10 oct 2019
Due date:      25 oct 2019
Task complete: No
```

Comment: Please share an example of the input file `tasks.txt`

Comment: @user56700 I just added the contents of the text file to the question.

Comment: I think it will be better to upload tasks.txt on a drive and share the link here.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rm3dJ_5Msk_uwb32HYMkW4w_Fb-bGAyK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That is the link to the textfile

Comment: @Ophethile Actually, for future questions, please do *not* link to data from an external source, that wasn't good advice from saad_saeed. The link might go bad in the future which will make this post useless for future readers. Instead, create a small sample dataset that reproduces the problem, and include that in the question as text that can be copy-and-pasted, cf. [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

```
outputs = []
for i, x in zip(string1, string2):
    outputs.append(i + ":" + x)
print(outputs)
```

`outputs` will be a list of the concatenated strings. You can combine the individual outputs together if you like with the `str.join()` method:

```
",".join(outputs)
```

will combine all the outputs together, with commas in between.

---

If you want to be fancy, you can do it all on nearly one line:

```
info = "Assigned to | Task | Task description | Date assigned | Due date | Task complete".split('|')
with open("tasks.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print(",".join(i + ":" + x for i, x in zip(info, line.split(','))))
```

But only if that doesn't confuse you or anyone else who reads your code.

Comment: I understand your code but the problem now is that the text is not readable. I want the output to be an easy read for someone who has no clue on code. I want the contents of string1 to be on the left and the contents of string2 to be on the right in each line. Not sure you understand though

Comment: I have added an example of the desired output to the question

Comment: You don't have to use `str.join`, not an array to store things. The key is the `for i, x in zip(string1, string2):` loop. That'll give you `i` and `x`, one by one.